# How to make the job history of SQL server agent more readable?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-agent

I want to see the the job history in a neat format. Currently, I just export it to a log file in which everything appears as a big line of text, without any formatting. How do i get it in a more readable form ?

Thanks.

Comment: I want to visualize SQL Server Agent job history.

Comment: Used those keywords and got this - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14080/whats-a-good-tool-for-visualizing-sql-agent-jobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 2 software options:

1. [SQL Job Manager](http://www.idera.com/productssolutions/freetools/sqljobmanager) - Looks more "professional"
2. [SQLjobvis](http://www.sqlsoft.co.uk/sqljobvis.php)

If you can't (or don't want to) use a free or opensource software, then your other options are to write queries and scripts yourself.

1. [Querying SQL Server Agent Job History Data](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2850/querying-sql-server-agent-job-history-data/).
2. [How to query currently running SQL Server Agent jobs](http://sqlconcept.com/2011/06/25/how-to-query-currently-running-sql-server-agent-jobs/).

[image: SQLjobvis is the SQL Server Agent history viewer]

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way, without installing unknown software by some obscure company ? This could be a problem when the target machine does not allow installation of software.

Comment: Just updated the answer. If you can't use software, then you'll have to write scripts and reports yourself.